# Integrating JavaScript Jasmine test in TFS in the cloud

Tags: tfs, build, jasmine

I am using Jasmine JavaScript Tests and would like to include them on my buildserver in the cloud (TFS, visualstudio.online). Has everyone ever done that and can help me out?

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: in addition to my question above, I use Karma

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx

You need to get http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/ (by NuGet), this enabled's you to run the javascript tests from the command line - then you setup your build controller properties and build definition to run js tests.

Only thing to remember, is that tests (specs) are depending on some files, and the run individually, so you need to add the

`/// <reference path="`

to the js specs. You could make a defaultReferenes.js with all the references, and then just add the defaultReferences to the specs.